# Does linealization in scala affect the way binding of internal types occur?

Tags: scala

```
trait Root { type T <: Root }
trait A extends Root { type T <: A }
trait B extends Root { type T <: B }
trait C extends A with B
```

The above code does not compile because the binding of type T in C is type T <: B
which obviously fails to subsume the binding type T <: A of T in type A.
Why is the type T of C bound to type T<:B and not type T<:A? Is it because of linealization?

Comment: What would you expect the type of `T` to be? Because if you override it to `C` _(which seems like the only sane value)_ it compiles. - Anyways, what are you trying to model here, this scheme is very fragile and it is easy to break the implicit contract of returning the same subtype.

Comment: This is just an example i come across while studying the scala documentation. I asked the question out of curiosity rather than a specific use case.

Answer (score 1):

Following the principle of Liskov. `C` being a subtype of `A`, `B` and `Root` has to satisfy all those contracts.
Thus, it has to have a inner type `T` which has to be a subtype of `A`, `B` and `Root`.

So, it is not bounded to `T <: B` or can not be bounded to `T <: A`, it has to be bounded to both.
For some reason, the compiler can't infer a proper type for `T` or maybe it simply decides that it is better in this case for the user to be explicit instead of inferring.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. What threw me off a bit is whats written in the documentation where it states that type T of C is bound to type T<:B. There's obviously a reason why thats the case, unless its an error.
https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/05-classes-and-objects.html#overriding

Comment: @Kamau The documentation is correct, it says exactly the same I said but with different wording. BTW, if you are new to the language I wouldn't recommend you the **specs** those are formal and are intended for maintainers of the language and creators of tools. - Consider the [**tour of scala**](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/tour-of-scala.html) or some [**courses**](https://docs.scala-lang.org/learn.html) instead.

Comment: Thanks for the response, i've actually been developing in scala for atleast 4 years, i just never read that documentation before. Now, the docs say "the class definition C is not well-formed because the binding of T in C is type T <: B". That clearly states that type T in C will be type T<:B.
Everything else that the docs say is crystal clear, what i am trying to understand is why "the binding of T in C is type T <: B" and not, say, T <: A.

Comment: @Kamau the linearization process starts from the right to the left. So first comes the own definition of `C` _(which here doesn't exist)_ then comes `B` _(from which it inherits `type T <: B`)_ then it goes to `A` and everything fails. So, the point is, if `C` comes to exists it has to be both, but the compiler has to start somewhere in the process to create it. Does that makes sense?

Comment: That makes sense, i thought linearization was the reason, i just wanted to double check on that. I appreciate it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A and B are different branches from Root. They are not compatible as the compiler indicates.

If you have a C that inherits both A and B, and you expect type T to be a subtype of both A and B, then you should have the type T to subtype C:

```
trait C extends A with B { type T <: C }
```

This compiles just fine.

Comment: I come across this example while studying the scala documentation and its crystal clear how to solve the problem as explained by in the documentation.
My question was a bit different from what you answered. 
In the documentation we read that the type T of C is bound to type T<:B. Why is that? Why is not boud to type T<:A instead?

Comment: Ok, so the documentation is wrong right?
https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/05-classes-and-objects.html#overriding